# The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

I'm trying to test my controllers using `xUnit` but getting the following error during execution of Customer Controller:

> "The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture
> data: CustomerController customerController"

**Test Class**

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    CustomerController _customerController;

    public UnitTest1(CustomerController customerController)
    {
        _customerController = customerController;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void PostTestSuccessful()
    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

        CustomerViewModel model = new CustomerViewModel()
        {
            Id = guid,
            Name = "testName",
            Email = "test email",
            PhoneNumber = "test phone",
            Address = "test address",
            City = "test city",
            Gender = "Male"
        };

        var actionResult = _customerController.Post(model);

        Assert.NotNull(actionResult);
        Assert.IsType<Task<IActionResult>>(actionResult);
        Assert.True(actionResult.IsCompletedSuccessfully);
    }
```

**CustomerController Class**

```
[Route("customers")]
public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;

    public CustomerController(ILogger<CustomerController> logger,
        ICustomerService customerService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _customerService = customerService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] CustomerViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var customerToBeSaved = viewModel.Adapt<CustomerServiceModel>();

        var customer = await _customerService.SaveAsync(customerToBeSaved);

        var result = customer.Adapt<CustomerViewModel>();

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Comment: `public UnitTest1(CustomerController customerController)` Your unit test needs to new up the controller (i.e. you need to remove the constructor parameter). There is no magical dependency injection that will inject it for you.

Comment: You should look at mocking libraries to mock your dependencies for  `CustomerController`. I personally like `moq`, but there are loads to choose from. `Rhino`, `SimpleMock` off the top of my head.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the testing framework, you need the mocking library to inject a mock object through DI in your testing classes. You can use Nmock, Moq or any other mocking library to setup the constructor injection.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/john_charles/mocking-in-net-with-moq/

http://nmock.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html

Answer (score 55):

What you are missing is the IClassFixture interface for the test class.  This will fix the problem...

```
public class UnitTest1 : IClassFixture<CustomerController>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Please explain the reason?

Comment: System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Class fixture type 'Controller' had one or more unresolved constructor arguments:

Comment: @vicNeo the reason is explained here: https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context .  xUnit is using the IClassFixture as hint that it needs to create and clean up a class fixture.  This is nonstandard use of an interface.  This is why this particular error is so hard to diagnose.  Both the implementation and the error message are inscrutable.

Answer (score 12):

Just new up CustomerController in the constructor, if you don't want to use any mocking framework.

Comment: "new up CustomerController" ?

Comment: @DMur they mean instantiate the controller in the class constructor e.g.  `_myPrivateProperty = new CustomerController();`

Answer (score -1):

Your Test Class Need to Inject ILogger and ICustomerService in Constructor

I Suggest you to Use Mock and Inject Controller Constructor Inputs in Test Class with Mocking

But Don't forget to Set Up the Mocked Objects or Interfaces

Learn More About Mock Here.....[enter link description here](https://softchris.github.io/pages/dotnet-moq.html#references)