# NSubstitute : Can not return value of type Task`1 for IMapperBase.Map (expected type List`1)

Tags: unit-testing, automapper, xunit.net, nsubstitute

I write a unit test, in the test I want to test my `CashCapitalService`.

in my service, I used `AutoMapper` for mapping my model to dto and reverse.

My Service is:

```cs
public class CashCapitalService : ICashCapitalService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public CashCapitalService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<List<CashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDto>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var allAsync = await _unitOfWork.CashCapitalRepository.GetAllAsync();

        List<CashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDto> cashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDtos = _mapper.Map<List<CashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDto>>(source:allAsync);
        return cashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDtos;
    }
}
    
public class CashCapitalService : ICashCapitalService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public CashCapitalService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<List<CashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDto>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var allAsync = await _unitOfWork.CashCapitalRepository.GetAllAsync();

        List<CashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDto> cashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDtos = _mapper.Map<List<CashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDto>>(source:allAsync);
        return cashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDtos;
    }
}
```

as you can see Automapper profile is:

```cs
public class CashCapitalInsertDtoProfile : Profile
{
    public CashCapitalInsertDtoProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDto, CashCapital>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

and in my unit test:

```cs
public class CashCapitalServiceTest
{
    private readonly CashCapitalService _cashCapitalService;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CashCapitalServiceTest()
    {
        _unitOfWork = Substitute.For<IUnitOfWork>();
        _mapper = Substitute.For<IMapper>();
        _cashCapitalService = new CashCapitalService(_unitOfWork, _mapper);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetAllAsync_Should_GetAllCashCapital()
    {
        //Arrange
        _unitOfWork.CashCapitalRepository.GetAllAsync().Returns(new List<CashCapital>());

        var cashCapitals = new List<CashCapital>()
        {
            new CashCapital()
            {
                InsertDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                AmountRial = 250000000, 
                Description = "tv,a lj,v"
            }
        };

        var cashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDtos = new List<CashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDto>()
        {
            new CashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDto()
            {
                AmountRial = 250000000, Description = "tv,a lj,v"
            }
        };

        //var returnValue = _mapper.Map(Arg.Any<List<CashCapital>>(), Arg.Any<List<CashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDto>>());
        //_cashCapitalService.GetAllAsync().Returns(returnValue);
        _mapper.Map(cashCapitals, cashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDtos).Returns(new List<CashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDto>()
        {
            new CashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDto()
            {
                AmountRial = 250000000, Description = "tv,a lj,v"
            }
        });
        var resultValue = _mapper.Map(cashCapitals, cashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDtos);

        _cashCapitalService.GetAllAsync().ReturnsForAnyArgs(resultValue);
        //Act
        var all = await _cashCapitalService.GetAllAsync();

        //Assert
        all.Should().BeOfType<List<CashCapitalInsertAndUpdateDto>>();
        await _unitOfWork.CashCapitalRepository.Received(1).GetAllAsync();
    }
}
```

When I run this test, failed and give me an error:

> Message:
> NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToTypeMismatchException : Can not return value of type Task`1 for IMapperBase.Map (expected type List`1).

I'm new in unit testing and the NSubstitute library, I don't know how to mock the AutoMapper.

Comment: There is no need to mock `IMapper`, just use the real thing.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu when I inject `IMapper` give me an error: **The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: IMapper mapper** and search result for this error [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155987/the-following-constructor-parameters-did-not-have-matching-fixture-data?answertab=active#tab-top](For the testing framework, you need the mocking library to inject a mock object through DI in your testing classes.)

Comment: Not really. Many people did this before you, without mocking AM.